# Error de sintaxis en un CASE

Tags: sql, mariadb

Tengo un problema de sintaxis. Tengo este código SQL:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') >= '09:00' AND str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') <= '18:00' 
            THEN str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') AS `time_to_HORARIO_TRABAJO` , count(*) AS `count`
        WHEN str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') >= '18:00' AND str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') <= '09:00'  
            THEN str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') AS `time_to_FUERA_HORARIO` , count(*) AS `count`
    END AS `time_to_resolve`
FROM `glpi_changes`
LEFT JOIN `glpi_users`.`users_id_recipient` ON `glpi_changes`.`users_id_recipient` = `users_id_recipient`.`id`
WHERE `glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve` IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH')
ORDER BY str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') ASC
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `` `time_to_HORARIO_TRABAJO` `` , count(*) AS `` `count` `` WHEN str_to_date(date' at line 7``

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Dicho esto, el problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que intentas usar un alias en una función de un `CASE`, ¿es lo que deseas? Imagino que no, que lo que deseas nombrar es el resultado del `CASE`. ¿Podrías explicar qué quieres hacer con tu consulta?

Comment: La sentencia case está evidentemente, mal, pero, ¿qué es lo que quieres lograr? Pregunto, porque leyendo el código de la consulta, no se logra determinar con claridad cuál es tu intención. Sugiero incluir una breve explicación y algunos datos de ejemplo de la entrada y la salida que quieres producir con esa entrada.

Comment: el when no puede devolver dos campos.. debe devolver uno solo... y el count(*) justamente ya va a contar al sacarlo del case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que sufres es debido a que estás intentando darle nombre a un campo antes de finalizar su definición.

Es decir, estás haciendo lo siguiente:

```
CASE 
    WHEN str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') >= '09:00' AND str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') <= '18:00' 
        THEN str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') AS `time_to_HORARIO_TRABAJO` , count(*) AS `count`
    WHEN str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') >= '18:00' AND str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') <= '09:00'  
        THEN str_to_date(date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH') AS `time_to_FUERA_HORARIO` , count(*) AS `count`
END AS `time_to_resolve`
```

Donde el nombre que quieres dar a ese campo es `time_to_resolve` (el último, el que va tras el `END`), pero al mismo tiempo **DENTRO** del `CASE` intentas dar nombre a algo que no es un campo:

```
THEN str_to_date(
  date_format(`glpi_changes`.`time_to_resolve`, '%HH'), '%HH'
) AS `time_to_FUERA_HORARIO` , count(*) AS `count`
```

Eso produce el error. No puedes dar al resultado de `date_format` nombre de campo porque no lo es, es parte de una estructura condicional `CASE` que aún no ha terminado de definirse.

Para contar los registros que están dentro o fuera del horario te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN TIME(time_to_resolve) BETWEEN '09:00' AND '18:59' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) time_to_HORARIO_TRABAJO,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN TIME(time_to_resolve) BETWEEN '09:00' AND '18:59' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    ) time_to_FUERA_HORARIO
FROM glpi_changes
WHERE time_to_resolve IS NOT NULL
```

Para empezar, no es necesario que extraigas la parte de hora para volver a convertir en hora para redondear. Puedes hacer la comprobación directamente con el operador `BETWEEN`.

Para continuar, sumamos cada registro que esté dentro del rango horario o no lo esté cambiando el orden del valor que devuelve el `CASE`.

Puedes ver un ejemplo en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x1GwLnJLkGefdjzJbDPg41/0

Comment: Muchas Gracias Oscar por tu respuesta. Te comento que efectivamente ya el error de sintaxis no aparece, pero el resultado que obtendo con condice con la realidad. Yo creo que algo tiene que ver con que el time_to_resolve es un campo date, mi intención fue despejar el horario para poder comparar.. me puedes ayudar? Gracias.-

Comment: ¡Claro que puedo ayudarte! Pensé que era un campo `TIME` por el nombre. Puedes usar las funciones [`TIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) u `HOUR()` para quedarte únicamente con la parte del tiempo (sin la fecha) o solo la hora para la comparación de rango `BETWEEN`.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta con el cambio.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!